# Alternate in Access2007

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

Alternate in Access

```
update category set name='hell' where categoryid=287

if @@rowcount=0 begin 
    insert into category(categoryid,name,path,parentcategoryid,creationdate) values (287,'a','a',12,'')
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternate in access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295708/alternate-in-access-database)