# Alternate in access database

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I want to check whether a row exists or not before inserting a new one in Access 2007.
I have the following working query in SQL Server but I'm having trouble converting it to Access.

```
update category set name='hell' where categoryid=287
if @@rowcount=0
begin
insert into category(categoryid,name,path,parentcategoryid,creationdate) values (287,'a','a',12,'')
end
```

Comment: I want to check whether a row exists or not before inserting a new one in access 2007 . Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update category set name='hell' where categoryid=287;

if not exists(select * from Category where categoryid=287)
    insert into category(categoryid,name,path,parentcategoryid,creationdate) 
values (287,'a','a',12,'');
```